# Page size doesn't work after auto setting pdf page height

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf-generation

I am generating pdf from html with 79mm width it is not working **width:79mm**

```
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page {
            width: 79mm;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
    </style>
```

and I am using with size so have to fix height then page breaks when dynamic values are more **size: 79mm 250mm;**

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page {
            size: 79mm 250mm;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by defining width and height in page size

```
@page {
        size: 79mm 270mm;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably misunderstand the usage of **"page-break-inside"** CSS property. according to [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm), the usage of **"page-break-inside"** is for some tags inside your HTML file. For example here I added the code of a simple "HTML" and "CSS" and used your style in that for `p` tags (**not inside @page rule** because according to [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) You **can't** change all CSS properties with @page):

```css
#page {
    background-color: rgb(226, 229, 238);
    color: #01C247;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

strong {
    color: red;
}

p {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>my site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page {
            size: 79mm 250mm;
        } 

        
        p {
            page-break-inside : avoid;
        }
        
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="page">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>
        
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="page">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>para end</strong> sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>

        <p>
            hamid davodi sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="page">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="page">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
    </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quas, tempora, nihil odit, mollitia harum illo cum placeat unde animi voluptatum dolorem quod. Aspernatur nihil repellendus optio dignissimos officia quidem!
        </p>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

If you try to print the above code in a browser (with `ctrl+p`) you will notice that paragraphs (that are cleared with **red border-bottom**) are not printed between pages, I mean that all texts of **a single** paragraph is in one page and **not** some of text in one page and the remaining text in the next page. you can comment

```
p {
   page-break-inside : avoid;
}
```

part to see the **difference** at printing. So for solving your problem I think you can probably apply "page-break-inside" to the tag that contains **payment details** section of your site.

Comment: I have a simple requirement that how to auto adjust the height in the page size.

Comment: what do you mean by "auto adjust"? you must define a number for the height! if your content are not in the right layout, you must change the layout and **this** is the responsibility of web designer. one way to do that is to use CSS properties like **page-break-inside**. if it is not enough, you must define other styles at **print** state to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, 

I have solved this problem by defining width and height in page size